# Qt: internationalization of images

Tags: c++, c, linux, internationalization, qt

I am aware of utilities like GNU `gettext` for making the software multilingual.
You give it a string id and it will return the translated string.

But I also need this for images in Qt.
For example, if I am displaying an image in `en_US` locale, I want to display a different version of the image if say `ja_JP` or `fr_FR` locale is set.
Qt doesn't recommend this. But I still need to do this.
I am working on C/C++, Linux.

Is there any standard way(like `gettext`) of achieving this for images?
Any suggestions on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the [resource system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html) allows you to specify the language each resource is associated with the `lang` attribute in the `.qrc` file.